# Material Ui-pickers: Open Calendar on Input focus & through Calendar Adornment

Tags: html, material-ui

This is the Material-Ui Pickers library:
https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/datepicker

If you scroll to InlinePickers you will see three examples I want to use the one at the end with the calendar icon in the input field. The issue is if you enable that then the user is able to edit the field and enter dates. However, I want the input field to remain the same where it opens the calendar when you focus on the Input.

So I would like to be able to open the calendar either on focus or when you click the calendar.

Also, Why does feeding the views prop ["year", "month", "day"] still only display month and day. Is it possible to display year as well while keeping the month in text instead of number format?

```
              <InlineDatePicker
                keyboard
                label={"Start Date"}
                value={startDate}
                onChange={(e) => {this.handleDateChange(e, 'start')}}
                className={styles.dateInput}
                minDate={this.getMinDate()}
                views={["year", "month", "day"]}
              />
```

Comment: Try to set `openTo='"year"`

Comment: I used the moment.format function to it instead made things easier

Comment: I am looking for a solution to a similar problem, i.e. opening the calendar both when the input is clicked and when the calendar is clicked. Did anyone find the solution for this?